# homotopy type of complement of subspace arrangement

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, gt.geometric-topology

I am studying the homotopy type of a space,and i hope it would be a $K(\pi,1)$ space.
now i have find its covering,once we can say the covering is $K(\pi,1)$,so is the space
itself.and the covering is

$\mathbb{R}^4-M$ where $M=M_1\cup M_2\cup M_3\cup M_4$,

$M_1=\{(x,y,z,w)|x,y \in \mathbb R,z,w \in\mathbb Z\}$

$M_2=\{(x,y,z,w)|y,z \in \mathbb R,x,w \in\mathbb Z\}$

$M_3=\{(x,y,z,w)|x,w \in \mathbb R,y,z \in\mathbb Z\}$

$M_4=\{(x,y,z,w)|z,w \in \mathbb R,x,y \in\mathbb Z\}$

I guess $\mathbb{R}^4-M$ is $K(\pi,1)$ space,can someone help prove this?

Answer (score 1):

Since you arrangement is so simple, there are must be some purely topological methods to check asphericity (or non-asphericity) of its complement. This is a well-developed subject I do not know much about.

I am more familiar with the geometric approach developed by Daniel Allcock (following predictions of Gromov) in  [this paper](http://www.ma.utexas.edu/users/allcock/research/branched.pdf). Unfortunately, the result in Allcock's does not apply to your arrangement because it is not "normal" (as defined in the paper). Allcock has a sequel in works where he gives a definitive answer to the question of asphericity for a large class of arrangements including the one you care about; if everything fails you might want to ask him for a preliminary version.

Comment: I guess (from the question) that the initial problem concerns a subset in $T^4$ and suggest to think in terms of it - try to fiber it, retract...

Comment: Petya, I agree, this might be easier.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a sketch of a solution. As Petya tells us, $\mathbf{R}^4\setminus M$ is invariant under the action of $\mathbf{Z}^4$ by integral translations, so it suffices to show that the image of $\mathbf{R}^4\setminus M$ in $T^4=\mathbf{R}^4/T^4$ is a $K(\pi,1)$. Denote this image by $N$. It is mapped to the 2-torus by $p:[x,y,z,w]\mapsto [x,y]$ where the square brackets stand for the images in the tori. $N$ is homotopy equivalent to $p^{-1}$ of the wedge $W$ of two circles given by $[x]=[1/2]$ and $[y]=[1/2]$. Set $X=S^1\times (S^1\vee S^1)$. The preimage $p^{-1}(W)$ is homotopy equivalent to two copies of $X$ joined along $pt\times (S^1\vee S^1)$, with a circle in each of the copies deleted; the deleted circles correspond to the two different circles of $S^1\vee S^1$, so $p^{-1}(W)$ is homotopy equivalent to the wedge of two 2-tori, and hence so is $N$.

Comment: It is $M_1$, etc. that is homotopy equivalent to $p^{-1}(W)$, not all of $M$. Also, the preimage $p^{-1}(W)$ has cohomology in dimension 3, so cannot be homotopy equivalent to $X$ or any 2-complex. Anyway, the question is about the complement of $M$, not $M$ itself. For $M$, you can apply Gromov's CAT(1) link condition to see that $M$ is locally CAT(0), and thus aspherical.

Comment: Tom, thanks, I misread the question and used $M$ for the complement. This has been fixed. Re "the preimage $p^{−1}(W)$ has cohomology in dimension 3": why? 

Comment: Since you were talking about $M$, I had taken $p$ as being defined from $T^4\to T^2$, rather than from $T^4\setminus \bar{M}\to T^2$. Now it seems clear that you meant the latter, so I withdraw my objection.

Comment: Hi,algori.Thank you for your answer.I am eager to get a clear picture of the solution.would you please talk about some details.
---student